# get a particular element in web component iteration

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, iteration

I want actually to be able to get an attribute on a particular item in the web component iteration, but cannot get it to work.

Look for instance the following code :

```
<template>
    <template for:each={pills} for:item="item">

       <lightning-pill 
               key={item} 
               label={item.label} 
               value={item.value} 
               onremove={handleRemove}>
        </lightning-pill>
    </template>    
</template>
```

When I clicked on the delete button on one particular pill in the list, I'm calling the method handleRemove for this item, but in my js I cannot get the reference to the particular item. Here is my js code :

```
 handleRemove (event) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('## set the value in the list :',event);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('## detail:',JSON.stringify(event.detail));
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('## item:',event.detail.item);      

}
```

The event.detail attribute is null. 
The event.target attribute also is null.

I don't know which attribute will return me the value or label of the selected pill.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference component properties that are not available or don't exist

for example:

`event.target.label` will work,

`event.target.value` will not.

you can find a reference of available properties in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill/specification)